# (editText.getBackground == Drawable) always returns false, why?. To be consistent it must return true, how?

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, drawable

I am wring an android app. It contains some `EditText` fields. I also wrote a custom background for them.

The custom background is at **res/drawable/bordered_edttext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" /> 
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />   
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
</shape>
```

The `EditText` refers to it

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_period"
        ...
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_edttext"
        ...
        />
```

Then at the activity

```
   Drawable editText_background;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      ...
      ...
      editText_background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bordered_edttext);
      boolean isbackground =  (et_period.getBackground() == editText_background);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The background status is " + isbackground, 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
```

The result of the toast is always: "The background status is **false**". It must be true.

Comment: Drawable can not be compare with `==`. Use equals instead... By the way what you are doing ???

Comment: @PankajKumar Thank you for help. I wrote two backgrounds. One is used when the input is valid, and the other is used when the input is invalid. So I need to check at run time which one is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's false because it's 2 different object even if the "image" is same. The first one is the object whose your Edittext create, and the second one is your drawable from your resource.

if you want to compare 2 drawable you should use `.equals`

try this:

```
et_period.getBackground().getConstantState()
        .equals(editText_background.getConstantState());
```

Answer (score 0):

just check Bellow Code Drawble can not companre with `==` you have to use `equals` method for it

```
    editText_background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);
    // boolean isbackground = (getConstantState()
    // .equals(editText_background.getConstantState()););
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "The background status is "
                    + tv.getBackground().getConstantState()
                            .equals(editText_background.getConstantState()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```